# Cumulative sum with two conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, cumulative-sum

I´m just starting to use python and pandas to improve my workload. I have df as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Div': [2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3], 
'date': ['01/09/2020', '01/09/2020', '01/09/2020','02/09/2020',
'01/09/2020', '01/09/2020', '01/09/2020', '02/09/2020'],
'income': [1000,1500,1000,500,700,2000,1000,6000],
'total':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
})
```

I need to calculate the cumulative total for each row while the div column doesn´t change.
So far I´ve managed to do it this way:

```
df2=df
for i in df.index:
    for j in df2.index:
        if (df.loc[i,'Div']==df2.loc[j,'Div'] and df2.loc[j,'date']<=df.loc[i,'date']):
            df.loc[i,'total']+=df2.loc[j,'income']
```

The result is this:

| Div | date | income | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 01/09/2020 | 1000 | 3500 |
| 2 | 01/09/2020 | 1500 | 3500 |
| 2 | 01/09/2020 | 1000 | 3500 |
| 2 | 02/09/2020 | 500 | 4000 |
| 3 | 01/09/2020 | 700 | 3700 |
| 3 | 01/09/2020 | 2000 | 3700 |
| 3 | 01/09/2020 | 1000 | 3700 |
| 3 | 02/09/2020 | 6000 | 9700 |

It works, but my original file has 13000 rows and it takes more than 2 hours to finish.
I´ve been reading around the web and everywhere it´s said that iteration should be avoided while using pandas but I can´t find a solution that fits my problem.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

One nice way of doing this would be using [`Groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
In [2684]: df['total'] = df.groupby(['Div', 'date'])['income'].transform('cumsum')
In [2686]: df['total'] = df.groupby(['Div', 'date'])['total'].transform('max')

In [2687]: df
Out[2687]: 
   Div        date  income  total
0    2  01/09/2020    1000   3500
1    2  01/09/2020    1500   3500
2    2  01/09/2020    1000   3500
3    2  02/09/2020     500    500
4    3  01/09/2020     700   3700
5    3  01/09/2020    2000   3700
6    3  01/09/2020    1000   3700
7    3  02/09/2020    6000   6000
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to

- compute total as cumulative sum fixing div?
  Use: `groupby`

[image]

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
'Div': [2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3], 
'date': ['01/09/2020', '01/09/2020', '01/09/2020','02/09/2020',
'01/09/2020', '01/09/2020', '01/09/2020', '02/09/2020'],
'income': [1000,1500,1000,500,700,2000,1000,6000],
'total':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
})

df['total'] = df.groupby("Div date".split()).cumsum()
display(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# step 1 calculate the sum income by group 'Div' and 'date'
df1 = df.groupby(['Div','date'])['income'].sum().reset_index()
#   Div date    income
# 0 2   01/09/2020  3500
# 1 2   02/09/2020  500
# 2 3   01/09/2020  3700
# 3 3   02/09/2020  6000


# step 2 calculate the cumsum income by 'Div'
df1['total'] = df1.groupby('Div')['income'].cumsum()
# Div   date    income  total
# 0 2   01/09/2020  3500    3500
# 1 2   02/09/2020  500 4000
# 2 3   01/09/2020  3700    3700
# 3 3   02/09/2020  6000    9700



# step3 merge the origin df with total column
del df['total']
pd.merge(df, df1[['Div', 'date', 'total']], on=['Div', 'date'], how='left')

#   Div date    income  total
# 0 2   01/09/2020  1000    3500
# 1 2   01/09/2020  1500    3500
# 2 2   01/09/2020  1000    3500
# 3 2   02/09/2020  500 4000
# 4 3   01/09/2020  700 3700
# 5 3   01/09/2020  2000    3700
# 6 3   01/09/2020  1000    3700
# 7 3   02/09/2020  6000    9700
```

Answer (score 0):

group by `Div` and `date` to use `sum` and then group by `Div` to use `cumsum`, then assign the column `total` with the calculate result.

```
result = (
df.set_index(['Div', 'date'])
  .assign(
      total=df.groupby(['Div', 'date'])['income'].sum().groupby("Div").cumsum()
  ).reset_index()
)
result
```

output:

```
    Div date        income  total
0   2   01/09/2020  1000    3500
1   2   01/09/2020  1500    3500
2   2   01/09/2020  1000    3500
3   2   02/09/2020  500     4000
4   3   01/09/2020  700     3700
5   3   01/09/2020  2000    3700
6   3   01/09/2020  1000    3700
7   3   02/09/2020  6000    9700
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this:

```py
precalc = df.groupby(["Div", "date"]).sum().reset_index().set_index("date")
df["total"] = df.apply(lambda row: precalc[precalc["Div"]==row["Div"]][:row["date"]]["income"].sum(), axis=1)
```

precalc basically sums for all the pairs ("Div", "date"). Then run `apply` on each row of the table to create the `total` which is the sum of all precalc rows for the matching Div and with dates ranging from the beginning to the row's date.

My theory here is by doing the pre-calculation ahead of time, you avoid having to do this for no reason while creating the cumulative sum. So essentially assuming there are lots of rows for a given Div and date.